# Can a lower bound for this weakening of Goldbach's conjecture be reached?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, entropy, goldbach-type-problems

Say a non negative integer $r$ is a primality radius of $n$ if both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime, and that a non negative integer $w$ is a Galois radius of $m$ if $\omega(m-w)=\omega(m+w)=1$, where $\omega$ counts the prime factors regardless of multiplicity. Say furthermore that $w$ is a strict Galois radius (SGR for short) of $m$ if it is a Galois radius of $m$ but not a primality radius thereof.

Can one get a lower bound for the number $W(n)$ of Galois radii of $n$, unconditionally or under some widely believed conjecture like (G)RH or Hardy-Littlewood conjecture (but obviously not Goldbach's conjecture itself)? If yes, can a proof that the proportion of SGR among Galois radii of $n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity provide a lower bound for the number of primality radii of $n$?

Edit July 14th 2022: say a Galois radius $w$ of $n$ is of level $l=ab$ and rank $R=a+b$ if $n-w=p^{a}$ and $n+w=q^{b}$ with $p$ and $q$ primes and $a$ and $b$ positive integers. Say $D_{n}(w):=(p^{a},q^{b})$ is the Goldbach-Galois pair for $n$ associated to $w$ and define its entropy $H(D_{n}(w))$ as $-\frac{a}{R}\log_{2}(\frac{a}{R})-\frac{b}{R}\log_{2}(\frac{b}{R})$ where $\log_{2}$ is the base $2$ logarithm.
Could we prove the maximal possible value of this entropy is attained, this may bring us closer to a proof of Goldbach's conjecture.

Edit August 1st 2022: adopting the viewpoint of geometry of numbers, one can figure out that an integer $p>1$ is prime if and only if a block made of $p$ squares has trivial isometry group whatever its configuration. That way associating to an integer $n$ the number of configurations $\Omega_{G}(n)$ of a block of $n$ squares having $G$ as isometry group and defining the corresponding entropy as $S_{G}(n):=\log\Omega_{G}(n)$, one may solve "physically" the problem of determining a Goldbach decomposition of an even integer $2N$ by maximizing the sum of the entropies $S_{e}(N_{1})$ and $S_{e}(N_{2})$ over all partitions of $2N$ of the form $N_{1}+N_{2}$.

The two viewpoints above may be unified if we consider a "discrete flow" $\Phi_{r}(2N):=(N-r,N+r)$ for increasing integral values of $r$ and associate to it the total entropy $S_{e}(N-r)+S_{e}(N+r)$.

Comment: I doubt it. The parity struggle is real. I could very well be wrong, but it might not be known whether every large even number can be written as $a+b$ where $\lambda(a)=\lambda(b)=-1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 one can show that every sufficiently large positive integer is the sum of four numbers with even parity by Lagrange's theorem on sums of 4 squares, and every odd integer $\geq 9$ is the sum of four numbers with odd parity by Ternary Goldbach.